# Fusion table infowindow not showing anymore

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm Google trusted photographer for the their Business Virtual Tour project in France.
I have developped a website www.visitme360.com showing virtual tours realised in France
The website is quite popular and based on a Fusion Table and Google Map

It worked quite well until a few days ago. :-(
Now, when you click on a marker, the infowindow is not showing anymore, neither on my website, nor on the Google Drive interface !

On my website (http://www.visitme360.com/index.php), you can use the orange buttons to filter the map by activities
This isn't working anymore as well

The code for the request is :

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({query:{select:"Adresse", from:"1Sk8GO5kNILZhmmXwzqPAGdhoNrk5xKs0Co8eRx4", where:"Secteur CONTAINS '" + critere + "'"}, map:map})
```

Do you have an idea why this is not working anymore all a sudden ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like the click event is no longer returning an object, so even attempting to use your own infowindow handling won't work.  Looks like an issue on Google's side, perhaps they are pushing a new release (but changing the API version doesn't seem to do anything useful).  For what its worth my maps that I checked ([one](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_AfricaMap_kml.html)) still work

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was a problem coming from Google.
Everything is working back fine now.

Comment: Please post your solution as an Answer and mark it, so the rest of the community can see how it's supposed to work, and see the hard done. :)